# Code Outlining, Classic ASP and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

Is there a way to enable code outlining for Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2005?  It outlines the HTML code pretty well and I get a big outline between <% and %>, but nothing for the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 has re-added support for classic ASP, but I don't believe either version supports the type of outlining you're looking for.

Comment: But it highlight classic asp if you use <script runat=server language=vbscript> instead. Not working for mixed html, vbscript but good for classes and functions.